# How to optimize python list comprehension

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm running this line of code to filter out all the null columns, Somehow it's slow
is there anyway to optimize it?

```
null_col = [col for col in dfs.columns if dfs[col].isnull().all()]
```

Comment: What is size of DataFrame? what is number of columns?

Comment: ranges from 90 to 120

Comment: How about `dfs.dropna('columns', 'all')`

Comment: I don't want to drop it, just print it out.

Answer (score 0):

One idea, not sure if faster:

```
out = dfs.columns[dfs.isnull().all()].tolist()
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, it's almost the same performance.

Comment: @Frozen - hmm, if all data are numbers try `out = dfs.columns[np.isnan(dfs.to_numpy()).all()].tolist()`

Comment: Unfortunately the data are mixed types. not just numbers